# pygame Surface.fill doesn't work (at all)

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to create a small ping-pong game with python and pygame, but I run into a huge problem: it doesnt work.
My code opens a window, but doesn't fill it. I've tried different variants of solving, but nothing seems to help. And I tried to compile this code in online compiler (Replit), but it doesn'tseem to work there neither.

```
import pygame

#screen initializing
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Ping-Pong')

for i in range(1000):
 screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
```

this code just opens a black window, no matter what number I write in. What can cause fill() function to not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `pygame.display.update()` at the end to update the screen